# How can I read from 3 different tables in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to use a custom reader, processor and writer in each step:

```
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory factory,
                         ItemReader reader,
                         ExpireAssessmentWriter writer,
                         AssessmentItemProcessor processor,
                         PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
                .<Assessment,Assessment>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    //update aggregate balance table
    @Bean
    public Step step2(StepBuilderFactory factory,
                      ItemReader reader,
                      BalanceItemWriter writer,
                      BalanceProcessor processor,
                      PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
                .<Assessment,Assessment>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    
    @Bean
    public Step step3(StepBuilderFactory factory,
                      ItemReader<Assessment> reader,
                      CustomWriter3 writer,
                      CustomItemProcessor3 processor,
                      PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step3")
                .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
                .<Assessment,Assessment>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
```

The first steps works fine but thats only when I leave this reader in the same class:

```
    private static final String READER_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN='TEST'";

@Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Assessment> reader(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Assessment>()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .name("AssessmentUtilityReader")
                .sql(READER_QUERY)
                .rowMapper(new AssessmentMapper())
                .build();
    }
```

How can I create a custom reader for each of these steps that will read it's own query?

Can I create a custom reader that extends JdbcCursorItemReader
and returns this same snippet of code? :

````
@Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Assessment> reader(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Assessment>()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .name("AssessmentUtilityReader")
                .sql(READER_QUERY)
                .rowMapper(new AssessmentMapper())
                .build();
    }
    ```
````

Comment: No. Using separate steps (where each step does one thing and does it well) is more appropriate IMO.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud -  
So I have to read/process and write to 3 different tables in the same DB so I have configured 3 different steps and have successfully completed the first step of the job which is reading from the 1st table using a custom itemProcessor and custom itemWriter But i can't figure out how to make each step use it's own customItemReader.

Let me edit the code snippet so you can see what I mean. 

T'hanks for the kind response.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question , **No** we cannot use multiple queries inside same reader .

But it is possible to have three different steps in same job where each step can query different table, before that please could you explain exact requirement to query three different tables in same job when tables are not related.

Comment: Please provide with a comment, if a comment can do the job, instead of posting an answer.
See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @ShivamJha , we need to have 50 reputation to comment . See [Who can comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)